# Swift: MapKit Custom Image Annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

In my app, I have a mapkit and annotations with different colors. But, there are just three color options (red, green, purple). So, I need to change annotations with custom image.

[I've followed this tutorial to create my mapview](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial)

Now, I have a **Artwork** class:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class Artwork: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let title: String
    let locationName: String
    let color: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(title: String, locationName: String, color: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.locationName = locationName
        self.color = color
        self.coordinate = coordinate

        super.init()
    }

    var subtitle: String {
        return locationName
    }

    // pinColor for disciplines: Sculpture, Plaque, Mural, Monument, other
    func pinColor() -> MKPinAnnotationColor  {
        switch color {
        case "Red":
            return .Red
        case "Purple":
            return .Purple
        case "Green":
            return .Green
        default:
            return .Green
        }
    }
}
```

Also, **VCMapView.swift** file:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

    // 1
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
        if let annotation = annotation as? Artwork {
            let identifier = "pin"
            var view: MKPinAnnotationView
            if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
                as? MKPinAnnotationView { // 2
                    dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
                    view = dequeuedView
            } else {
                // 3
                view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                view.canShowCallout = true
                view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
                view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIView
            }
            view.pinColor = annotation.pinColor()
            return view
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And I can add pins on my map like this in **viewdidload()**

```
// show artwork on map
let artwork = Artwork(title: "\(self.plate)",
locationName: "\(self.location)",
color: "\(self.color)",
coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longtitude))

self.mapView.addAnnotation(artwork)
```

All work perfect but need to add custom image to this architecture,  which part should I modify I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your architecture in my opinion, you should add an image property in the `Artwork` class and then use id in the `.image` property of `MKPinAnnotationView`.

ex:

```
view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
view.canShowCallout = true
view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIView
            }
view.image = UIImage(named:"your_image")
view.frame.size = CGSize(width: 30.0, height: 30.0) //not necessary but just to give you an idea how to resize just in case it is too large.
```

Comment: Nerkyator you saved my day! I am having a beer in your name. I spent 3 hours trying to change the size of my pin annotation. view.frame.size = CGSize(width: 30.0, height: 30.0) was so easy works well in Swift 3. I was trying adding constraints, view.sizeThatFits(width:, height:) nothing resize my image and if I just resize myself image quality became the issue. thanks!